# JWT token generation for apple api in php

Tags: php, jwt, app-store-connect, php-jwt

I am trying to generate JWT token for apple connect API (to get sales report) in php.

i tried this format (using firebase/php-jwt)

```
$Private_key = file_get_contents('AuthKey_XYZ.p8');

$Issuer_ID = 'XYZ';
$Key_ID = 'ZDJ';

$data = [
        'iss' => $Issuer_ID,
        'iat' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timestamp,
        'exp' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(20)->timestamp,
        'aud' => "appstoreconnect-v1"
];

$jwt = JWT::encode($data, $Private_key,'HS256', $Key_ID);
```

And receiving 401, did i missed something or the format is

Comment: Try read p8 file with below code and algo RS256:
`$keyfile = 'AuthKey_XYZ.p8';`
`$key = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://'.$keyfile);`

Comment: still same. even tried with new key (admin)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the JWT encryption algorithm you are specifying is wrong. Try setting it to 'ES256', e.g:
 `$jwt = JWT::encode($data, $Private_key,'ES256', $Key_ID);`

from the docs under "Create the JWT header"
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests